# MigraDox C# Checkboxes - Wingdings Not Working

Tags: c#, fonts, migradoc

I am needing to simulate a checkbox in a PDF I am generating using the MigraDoc library. I stumbled across two sources that offer essentially the same solution ([here](http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3160) and [here](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/676729/Migradoc-checkbox/))

However, I am not getting the expected results. Instead I am getting þ for boxes that are supposed to be checked, and ¨ for those that are to be unchecked. What might the issue be?

Snippet of my code

```
     para = section.AddParagraph();
        para.Style = "ListLevelOne";
         para.AddFormattedText("1 ", "Bold");
         para.AddFormattedText(IsQ1Checked ? "\u00fe" : "\u00A8", new Font("Wingdings"));
```

Comment: Are you using MigraDoc 1.50 beta 3b? Or an older version?

Comment: I am using version 1.32. Thanks.

Comment: With 1,32 make sure that font embedding is activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MigraDoc does not use the font "Wingdings", instead it uses a default font (could be MS Sans or so) and therefore you see the characters from a standard font, not the Wingdings symbol.

The problem is somewhere outside the code snippet you are showing here. Make sure the font Wingdings is installed on the computer.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually intended to be loaded in the viewer within a browser window. What fonts can be used in that environment?

Comment: MigraDoc will embed all fonts in the PDF file, thus the PDF file can be viewed everywhere. But when creating the PDF file, MigraDoc must have access to the font files in order to embed them. You create the PDF on a computer that probably does not give MigraDoc access to the Wingdings TTF file. And font embedding must be activated for MigraDoc 1.32 and older.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually to be used on a different device (an iPad) than my development machine. I suppose I will have to test it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to embed the font and ensure that MigraDoc uses unicode encoding instead of ansi:

```
private const bool unicode = true;
private const PdfFontEmbedding embedding = PdfFontEmbedding.Always;
//...
var pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(unicode, embedding);
```

http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/migradochelloworld-sample.ashx

Comment: Good point. I actually had it enabled already, but I still think this is an important suggestion.