# PDFsharp how to add checkboxes to document

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

I've been looking around on what's the best way to add a checkbox to a PDFsharp document.

So far I'm only able to add a string `"\u00fd"` with the Wingdings font. It kinda works only if the PDF document is opened with the Acrobat Reader. But if Chrome or IE opens it, instead of a checkbox, it will show a unreadable character.

Any ideas or better alternative (free or open source) to PDFsharp?

My requirement for the PDF document is very easy and just one or two reports.

Followed links provided by PDFsharp Novice to embed the font.

Draw the checkbox:

```
XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode,
                                              PdfFontEmbedding.Always);

XFont prevCheckboxFont = new XFont("WingDings", 12, XFontStyle.Regular, options);

XRect prevCheckboxPos = new XRect(XUnit.FromInch(3.20), XUnit.FromInch(3.30),
                                  XUnit.FromInch(1.25), XUnit.FromInch(.10));
string prevCheckboxText = "\u00FE";
gfx.DrawString(prevCheckboxText, prevCheckboxFont, XBrushes.Black,
               prevCheckboxPos, XStringFormats.TopLeft);
```

Comment: If you need help to fix your code then please show some code.

Comment: So it seems you are not using the latest version (1.50), but a very old version (1.32 or earlier). Does it work now? If not, would you provide a PDF? The code snippet does not show the code that draws the checkbox.

Comment: @PDFsharpNovice I added the part that draws the checkbox. It is working now. Chrome and IE are showing the correct checkbox on my laptop but  I need to run some more tests and run it on the server.  And I have the latest stable version 1.32.3057. Does this code looks correct or is there an updated way to do this?

Comment: @causita - Were you able to insert checkboxes?

Comment: @ncdreamy yes, I used the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use Wingdings to create checkboxes in PDF and they work with Adobe Reader, Firefox, and Chrome.

Make sure to embed the fonts in the PDF file.

With the old versions 1.32 and older you have to specify a flag to have the fonts embedded:

```
XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode,
                                              PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
XFont font = new XFont("Times New Roman", 12, XFontStyle.Regular, options);
```

With current versions (1.50 and higher) fonts are always embedded and the option was removed.

See also:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Unicode-sample.ashx
[MigraDox C# Checkboxes - Wingdings Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42977692/162529)

Comment: You (correctly!) ask the OP for some code. How comes that you yourself don't supply the code from the links you supplied, not even the pivotal code pieces?

Comment: @mkl The OP does not even indicate the version they use - usage has changed between 1.32 and 1.50. The link goes to the official project site and is unlikely to become broken. I don't like to create unmaintained copies of code. I don't like to write or copy code based on speculation without knowing the real cause for sure.

Comment: *"I don't like to create unmaintained copies of code."* - A commendable attitude in general but in this case this collides with the way stack overflow wants its answers: ["Always quote the most relevant part of an important link"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). That been said, *"The OP does not even indicate the version they use - usage has changed between 1.32 and 1.50."* - In that case I'd either assume the most current version(s) or ask the OP to clarify before answering.

Comment: I’m using the latest version.  I will check those 2 links and report back and put my code also. Thanks.

Comment: @PDFsharpNovice Great, that makes the answer a real answer.